# Accessing created column in another column

Tags: database, ssms, select-query

I just want to know if there's a way to access the new column that i created which is the 'Age' so that my condition in the next column will work ? here's my code , Advance Thank you for the response ^^
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YElKr.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use subquery as :

```
SELECT CompleteName,DateofBirth,CASE WHEN Age >=60 then 'Y' WHEN Age<60 then 
'N' ELSE 'Unknown' as IsSenior FROM (
SELECT LastName + ',' + FirstName + ',' + LEFT(MiddleName,1)+'.' as 
CompleteName,DateofBirth, DATE(YEAR,DateofBirth,GETDate()) as Age
) as A
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working now.^^//. Just a follow up question, what's the function of 'as A'  at the end of the query  ? i'm a beginner in t-sql so i dont know much

Comment: It's just the alias for the inside query assuming the whole query as A . Sometime while joining more tables and using subquery then there is confusion in the tables so by alias we can remove that confusion and it also helps in joining we can use alias as A or B instead of using the whole table name in join . Thanks for your curiosity .

Comment: Okay. Again, Thanks a lot.